# How can i replace the value of a variable dynamically in terraform based on a condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i have two modules:

```
module "vpc" {
..
..
}

module "subnet" {
 vpc = "${module.vpc.id}"
}
```

And the appropriate variables and output file.

Based on a condition, i would like to change the value of vpc in module subnet dynamically.
i.e  value of vpc can be either `"${module.vpc.id}"` or `"${var.vpcid}"`.
When i do this, i can create a new vpc and subnet ,when the value of vpc is set to - `"${module.vpc.id}"`  applying all the terrform modules,
and also make use of an existing vpc when the value of vpc is `"${var.vpcid}"`( here terraform apply with not include the vpc module)

I've tried to use expressions, used a local block with a condition outside of these two modules, but it ends up creating a new vpc.

```
locals {
vpctake = "${var.vpcch ? element(module.vpc.id, 0) : var.vpcid}"
}
```

where vpcch can be either true or false
and in the subnet module:

```
vpc = "${local.vpctake}"
```

Is there any way to implement this.

Comment: Can you show actually code of what have you tried and error messages. It may be easier to see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mistakes in your code:

- `vpcch` should be `vpcid`
- missing condition in your `local` block

Below is an example of how I would do it:

```
# vpcid with default value of empty string
variable "vpcid" {
  default = ""
}

# correctly defined local variable vpctake
locals {
  vpctake = "${var.vpcid == "" ? element(module.vpc.id, 0) : var.vpcid}"
}

module "subnet" {
 vpc = "${local.vpctake}"
}
```

With this, if `vpcid` is provided from command line:

```
terraform apply -var="vpcid=some-id"
```

`local.vpctake` will be `some-id`. Otherwise value from `element(module.vpc.id, 0)` will be used.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin however in this scenario - "local.vpctake will be some-id", when i run `terraform plan --target module.subnet`, it creates a new vpc, 
whereas i would want to  make use of the existing vpc id that i'm passing as a variable and not create a new vpc.

Comment: @Dilip Hi. To work with existing VPC you can use [data aws_vpc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/vpc). My answer was aimed at fixing your condition as it was incorrect. You can adapt the example to your requirements using aws_vpc data source.

Comment: Okay, Yea, Thank again @Marcin,Thanks for the correction and hint.